# Custom iterator asks Object instead my type Java

Tags: java, object, foreach, iterator, incomplete-type

I've made my own implementation of HashTable and want to build an iterator to make it possible to use forEach. MyHashTable is a generic class with K, V parameters.
Here is snippet from MyHashTable class:

```
@Override
public Iterator iterator() {
    return new MyHashTableIterator();
}

class MyHashTableIterator implements Iterator {
    private MyHashTableEntry[] entries;
    private int entriesIter;

    public MyHashTableIterator() {
        this.entries = entrySet();
        this.entriesIter = 0;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasNext() {
        return entriesIter < entries.length - 1;
    }

    @Override
    public MyHashTableEntry next() {
        return entries[entriesIter++];
    }
}
```

This seems to be ok for me, but when I try to use forEach somewhere it requires me to iterate using Object variable:

```
for (MyHashTable.MyHashTableEntry entry : wordDict) {
}
```

This code produces:

> Error: java: incompatible types: java.lang.Object cannot be converted to MyHashTable.MyHashTableEntry

How to make it work good, not using Object variable?

Comment: Replace the rawtype `Iterator` with `Iterator<MyHashTableEntry>`.

Comment: Thanks for answering! I replaced it with Iterator<MyHashTableEntry<K, V>>.
Now snippet:

    for (MyHashTable.MyHashTableEntry<String, Integer> entry:
             wordDict) {

        }

Produces Error:java: improperly formed type, type arguments given on a raw type

Comment: Is your `MyHashTableEntry` class also generic with K, V parameters?

Comment: Yes, it is generic also